# NSString to NSDate issue IOS7

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter, ios7

I'm using the following code to convert `NSString` to `NSDate`:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate convertStringToDate:strDate andFormatter:@"MM dd"];

+ (NSDate *)convertStringToDate:(NSString *)dateString andFormatter:(NSString *)formatter
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    // this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
    // if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatter];

    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

NSString is `@"07 15"`. But my NSDate is `nil`. On a simulator it is fine but on device with iOS7 it is nil.

Do you have any suggestions about it?

Comment: Is the timezone set on your device the same as the timezone on your computer? If `NSDateformatter dateFromString` conversion fails it will return nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code works in iOS 6, then this may just be a bug in iOS 7. Be sure to file a bug report if you think that's the case.

If it doesn't work in iOS 6, then it may be that a month and day aren't sufficient to specify a date. Try adding a year and see if you get a valid date that way.

Note that questions about iOS 7 should be posted to Apple's developer forums, not here.

Answer (score 2):

you may need to set the locale like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

I solved this problem including the locale to the formatter.
hope this helps.